# How to save my cookies and url to a txt file

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, fs

So I am able to log my Cookies and URL but I cannot try to set them to variables please help.

I set both of them to variables and I would just get the output of Promise {  }

```
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.xpath(`//*[@id="SIZE"]/option[2]`)).click();
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.xpath(`//*[@id="trackpants-ink"]/div/div[3]/form[1]/input[3]`)).click();
setTimeout(function(){
    driver.findElement(webdriver.By.xpath(`//*[@id="js-wrap"]/header/div[2]/form/div/div/div[2]/input`)).click();
    setTimeout(function() {
        driver.getCurrentUrl().then(url=> console.log(url)).catch(err=>console.log(err));
        setInterval(function() {
            driver.manage().getCookies().then(function (cookies) {
                console.log(cookies);
            }); 
        }, 2000);
    }, 2000);
}, 5000);
}
```

I want to set this to a variable (This is the cookies)

```
driver.manage().getCookies().then(function (cookies) {
console.log(cookies);
});
```

and I want to set this to a varible (This is the URL)

```
driver.getCurrentUrl().then(url=> console.log(url)).catch(err=>console.log(err));
```

Both of these when ran outputs to the console but it does not let me turn them into variables.
Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use 'let'. Try belows:

```
let cookiesData;
driver.manage().getCookies().then(function (cookies) {
console.log(cookies);
cookiesData = cookies;
});
```